# Should I use multiple-domain SSL certificate for subdomains with EV?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a web-site - for instance, https://website.com - and I need to provide an SSL certificate for this web-site and a couple subdomains - for instance, https://subdomain.website.com and https://my.website.com

In another situation, I would use **wildcard** SSL certificate, which works for subdomains, but I want an **Extended Validation** certificate with green address bar [(example image)](https://www.digicert.com/images/ev2.jpg). As far as I know, there are no **wildcard EV** certificates.

However, there are **multiple-domain EV** certificates. Can I use this one to provide security for my domain and its subdomains. Or are there any other more proper and\or cheaper options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your sub domains to have EV, then I'd go for the multiple domain ev.